# SQL server Looping through columns

Tags: sql

I have a table with multiple columns and I want to check if how many column has value greater than 5 like below.
Can you please help?
Thanks,
HHC

```
do i=1 to last_collumn;
 if column(i)>5 then count=count+1;
end;



Create TABLE have1  (
    id number(32),
    set1_a varchar(225),
    set1_b varchar(225),    
    set1_c varchar(225),
    set2_x varchar(225),
    set2_y varchar(225),    
    set3_n varchar(225)   
);
Insert into have1 (id,set1_a,set1_b,set1_c,set2_x,set2_y,set3_n) values (1,1,-333,200,1,1,'avb');
Insert into have1 (id,set1_a,set1_b,set1_c,set2_x,set2_y,set3_n) values (2,1,3,0,10,20,'ADULT');
Insert into have1 (id,set1_a,set1_b,set1_c,set2_x,set2_y,set3_n) values (2,1,3,0,1,1,'student');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Schema:**

> ```
> Create TABLE have1  (
>     id int,
>     set1_a varchar(225),
>     set1_b varchar(225),    
>     set1_c varchar(225),
>     set2_x varchar(225),
>     set2_y varchar(225),    
>     set3_n varchar(225)   
> );
> Insert into have1 (id,set1_a,set1_b,set1_c,set2_x,set2_y,set3_n) values (1,1,-333,200,1,1,'avb');
> Insert into have1 (id,set1_a,set1_b,set1_c,set2_x,set2_y,set3_n) values (2,1,3,0,10,20,'ADULT');
> Insert into have1 (id,set1_a,set1_b,set1_c,set2_x,set2_y,set3_n) values (2,1,3,0,1,1,'student');
> ```

**Query:**

> ```
> select *, 
> (case when set1_a>5 then 1 else 0 end +
> case when set1_b>5 then 1 else 0 end +
> case when set1_c>5 then 1 else 0 end +
> case when set2_x>5 then 1 else 0 end +
> case when set2_y>5 then 1 else 0 end ) Count_Of_Column_greater_than_5
> from have1
> ```

**Output:**

> id | set1_a | set1_b | set1_c | set2_x | set2_y | set3_n  | Count_Of_Column_greater_than_5
> -: | :----- | :----- | :----- | :----- | :----- | :------ | -----------------------------:
> 1 | 1      | -333   | 200    | 1      | 1      | avb     |                              1
> 2 | 1      | 3      | 0      | 10     | 20     | ADULT   |                              2
> 2 | 1      | 3      | 0      | 1      | 1      | student |                              0

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c625ff5e83a52d2ce8984c0b5720faf5)*

Answer (score 0):

You haven't tagged your RDBMS so this may or may not need some tweaking

```
select Sum(
    Iif(set1_a>5, 1, 0)+
    Iif(set1_b>5, 1, 0)+
    Iif(set1_c>5, 1, 0)+
    Iif(set2_x>5, 1, 0)+
    Iif(set2_y>5, 1, 0)
) as TotalColumnsWithValueGreaterThan5
from have1
```

result: 3